# How to log in to Windows with AD Group Name only

Tags: windows, authentication

Is there any way to log in to Windows just by using a group's name?

For example, I have a group "authenticated_users", with a single user "auth_user"

I can log in with "auth_user" with its password, but I simply want to log in using "authenticated_users" as the username and with no password.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no way that you can simply use a group name to log in to a Windows machine.

Just remember that *A group name is **not** an username*.

Moreover don't you think it is a security breach, because a windows machine have many default groups and if it was possible to log in using merely a group name then any one would be able to log in to your windows machine and I think you won't like any stranger logging in to your windows machine. This link may help you to know what groups are: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726978.aspx